# How to grab parts of URL and paste it somewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I need a javascript (preferably) for my mediawiki website that will grab the end of the url, for example from
http://aionpowerbook.com/powerbook/125004192
I would like it to grab the ID 125004192 and then add it somewhere on the same page like this

```
<a id="various3" href="http://aionpowerbook.com/view.php?item=placed_id">
```

the begging would be static and the ID would be added after '?item=', which would result in:

```
<a id="various3" href="http://aionpowerbook.com/view.php?item=125004192">
```

Is this even possible?

Update:
I had to edit your suggestions a little bit but at the end it worked

```
<a id="various3" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  var itemid = document.URL.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
  var a = document.getElementById('various3');
  if (a) {
    a.href = "http://aionpowerbook.com/view.php?item=" + itemid;;
  }
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can extract the id like this: `document.getElementById('various3').href.split('=').pop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var link = document.getElementBYId("various3");
var id = document.URL.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
link.href = "http://aionpowerbook.com/view.php?item=" + id;
```

Comment: sorry but didn't work either.
I made a page that only consist of that <a link from my first post and this script and it's not doing anything.
[link](http://aionpowerbook.com/powerbook/111222333)